# Страница некорректно отображается на некоторых мобильных устройствах (на iphone)

Tags: html, css, кроссбраузерность, кроссплатформенность

Делаю веб-страницу, еще только новичок. Столкнулась с тем, что страница некорректно отображается в мобильной версии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот так выглядит в браузере
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, что случилось. Может кто-нибудь натолкнуть на решение данной проблемы?

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a,
a:hover,
button,
button:hover,
.anime {
  -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Poor Story', cursive;
  font-size: 1.2vmax;
  line-height: 2vmax;
}

.wrap {
  width: 76vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  background: url(img/banner2.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

@keyframes go-down {
  from {
    padding-top: 0vh;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  to {
    padding-top: 16vh;
    color: #555459;
    text-shadow: 2px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
}

#top_header #logo {
  animation: go-down 4s;
  font-size: 2.1vmax;
  text-shadow: 2px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding-top: 16vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

#top_header {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  color: #555459;
  justify-content: space-between;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#main_nav li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10vh;
}

#main_nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#main_nav {
  padding-top: 16vh;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  font-size: 2.1vmax;
  text-shadow: 2px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#main_nav a:hover {
  font-size: 2.4vmax;
  color: #35315b;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poor+Story" rel="stylesheet">
<header>
  <div id="top_header" class="wrap">
    <div id="logo">
      Hello, I'm Anastasia
    </div>
    <nav id="main_nav">
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">My works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Вставь код так, чтобы его можно было запустить здесь, или дай ссылку на Fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У блока `#main_nav` установлено свойство `flex-flow: row nowrap` из за `nowrap` пункты меню не переносятся и выходят за край. Задайте `flex-flow: row wrap`.